# I'm having trouble compiling my code in bash

Tags: c

I keep getting the same error code: "warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘float *’ [-Wformat=]"
My code is below, any help debugging it would be greatly appreciated!

```
//Program to compute the stress and strain in steel rods of different diametes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> //#include <math.h>

//Define Constants
#define PI 3.14f;

//Define Variables
float Es;
float D;
float P;

int main(void)

{
        Es = 3 * pow(10,7);

        for(P=50000; P<=100000; P=P+25000) {
                printf("\nCompression Load =     %f\n\n", &P);
                printf("Diameter        Stress        Strain\n");
                for(D=2; D<=5; D=D+1) {
                        float Area;
                                    Area = D * D / 4 * PI;
                        float Stress;
                                     Stress = P / Area;
                        float Strain;
                                Strain = Stress / Es;
                        printf("%f        %f        %f\n", &D, &Stress, &Strain);
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remove the `&` in the `printf` and you should be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%f` format specifier to `printf` expects a `double` as an argument.  What you are passing in instead (in multiple places) is the address of a `float`, i.e. a `float *`.  These are incompatible.

You need to remove the address-of operator `&` from these operands.  Then you'll be passing in `float` values which will automatically be converted to `double` values:

```
printf("\nCompression Load =     %f\n\n", P);

...

printf("%f        %f        %f\n", D, Stress, Strain);
```